# PHP preg_match fails even though regex pattern is present

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, regex-lookarounds

I want to reproduce this array of breadcrumbs, which each of the breadcrumbs less the last item of the breadcrumb.

What I have tried.  I have tried `preg_match`ing the pattern "/.*(?=\s»\s)/", which should grab everything prior to the last instance of `»`.  This was my attempted solution:

```
<?php
$breadcrumb = array (
  'More » Brackets & Mounting » StarTech MNRISERCLMP',
  'Printer Consumables » Toner Cartridges » Other Brand » Sharp MX27GTMA',
  'More » Audio Visual » TVs » Philips 43BDL4051T-EXG',
  'Servers » Server Cables & Accessories » Other Server Accessories » LINKBASIC LB-WCC09-655-CA'
);



foreach($breadcrumb as $breadcrumbs){
        preg_match("/.*(?=\s»\s)/",$breadcrumbs,$matches);
        echo $matches[1] . '<br />';
    }
```

gives:

> **Warning**:  Undefined array key 1 in **[...][...]** on
> line **13**
>  
>  **Warning**:  Undefined array key
> 1 in **[...][...]** on line **13**
>  
> **Warning**:  Undefined array key 1 in **[...][...]** on line
> **13**
>  
>  **Warning**:  Undefined array key 1 in
> **[...][...]** on line **13**

I understand the error is telling me there has been no match but logically I cannot see why the `preg_match` is failing.

Comment: Might be easier to `explode()` the string on `»` and then remove the last element from the resulting array and rebuild the string with `implode()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your result will be in `$matches[0]`:

```php
echo $matches[0] . '<br />';
```

Or try this pattern:

```php
preg_match("/(.+)\s»\s.+$/", $breadcrumbs, $matches);
echo $matches[1] . '<br />';
```

Comment: Very good - this seems to work.  What was wrong with my original pattern definition and what makes this one work where the other failed?

Comment: You have not specified a group in your pattern, so the result will be in `$matches[0]`. I have updated the answer.